# Typed.js freezes website when typing lesser than or greater than

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities, typed.js

I have just got typed.js and am having some trouble with making `<body>` be typed out so on the website it says `<body>`. Whenever I try running it, it just freezes. My code works when the string is changed to just `body` instead of `<body>`
**HTML**

```
<span class="typed"></span>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
        $(".typed").typed({
          strings: ["&#60body&#62"],
          typeSpeed: 100
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `<` and `>` by using `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".typed").typed({
    strings: ["&lt;body&gt;"],
    typeSpeed: 100
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.7/typed.min.js"></script>

<span class="typed"></span>
```